# Is there some type of email alert notification service when something happens to an EOS account?

Tags: notification, stake, unstake

I want to get an email alert notification when my balance gets unstaked. Is there such a notification service for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, EOS Authority provides such a service: https://eosauthority.com/alerts

Comment: who runs eos authority?

Comment: they're an independent block producer https://eosauthority.com/disclosures